# APNS Apple push notification service not receiving success message from apple

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

We are trying to send push notifications to api.push.apple.com. we are using Ruby on Rails on server side to send APNS. We are already using TLS 1.2 and HTTP2. We have tried both the ports 443 and 2197.

{:host=>"api.push.apple.com", : port=>"443", :certificate=>"Bag Attributes\n friendlyName: Apple Push Services: com.company.bundle\n localKeyID: BA 6F 55 DA D5 7A B4 D3 DC 84 B3 CE DC 8d 0A A5 2D 08 9A F4 \nsubject=UID = com.summit.2019, CN = Apple Push Services: com.summit.2019, OU = HHGY6CWBZB, O = MovingMedia AB, C = SE\n\nissuer=C = US, O = Apple Inc., OU = Apple Worldwide Developer Relations, CN = Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority\n\n-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\ [PEM Certificate Here] ---END PRIVATE KEY-----\n", :certificate_passphrase=>""}

Payload: {"aps"=>{"alert"=>"test for apn", "badge"=>14}}

Hexadecimal response: "\x00\x00\x18\x04\x00\x00" "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00"

When we unpack them we get the following response respectively: [0, 0, 1048 ] [0, 0, 65536]

We did some more debugging at our end and found the notifications were working when sending from terminal using the curl command but it was not working when sending through our server. We believe this is something with the server change from Apple for Push notification. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I recall having similar issues when I first tried implementing Apple Push Notifications via RoR. Instead of trying to manually get it right - I switched to the Houston gem and never looked back. Give this a try:

https://github.com/nomad/houston